# dummy types SML

Tags: list, sml

I was trying to do everything here, but nothing happened. The code is working properly when I call it with no empty list, but as soon as I put empty list [] things go wrong. It pops up with 'dummy types' warning and some error on the following code:

```
fun zip(xs1, x2) =
    case xs1 of
        [] => []
        | (h1::t1) => (case x2 of
                            [] => []
                            |   (h2::t2) => (h1, h2) ::zip(t1,t2));
```

The output is supposed to be a list created out of tuples that are heads of input lists with the length of the shorter list. As you can see in the picture there are no errors on code itself, at least not the one that compiler recognize, just when I call function with empty list.
[image]

I honestly have no idea what is going on there. Can someone please explain to me what this type of error means, and how can I fix the code not to have it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first attempt it zips correctly. In your second attempt you are forgetting a comma between your two lists. In your third attempt you are succeeding, but since the first parameter is polymorphic at the top-level, you are encountering 
the [value restriction](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction).

A prettier version of zip:

```
fun zip ([], _ys) = []
  | zip (_xs, []) = []
  | zip (x::xs, y::ys) = (x,y)::zip (xs, ys)
```

And a shorter, equivalent version:

```
fun zip (x::xs, y::ys) = (x,y)::zip (xs, ys)
  | zip _ = []
```

A tail-recursive version of zip from [Moscow ML's ListPair module](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/ListPair.sml#L3):

```
fun zip (xs, ys) =
    let fun helper (x::xr, y::yr, result) = helper (xr, yr, (x,y)::result)
          | helper (_, _, result) = List.rev result
    in zip' (xs, ys, []) end
```